# extra closing parentheses `)` at the end of og:url meta tag value on all Stack exchange pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, meta-tags

Funny thing I have noticed, literally all the pages in stackoverflow with open graph `og:url` meta tag has their URL value being appended with a closing parenthesis `)`.

I know that this tag does not affect SEO or anything in practice except an identifier in the open graph node. But this bothers me a little.

Below are the screenshots from various pages in the stack exchange sites. Looks like somebody forgot to remove an extra parentheses.

#### Screenshot from a stackoverflow question page

[image: Screenshot from a stackoverflow question page]

#### Screenshot from my user profile page

[image: Screenshot from my user profile page]

#### Stack exchange ask new question page

[image: Stack exchange ask new question page]

I'm not sure if this is the same case for all other stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This will be fixed in the next prod build.